# Covariance and Contra-variance w.r.t. row column and inverse change of basis matrix

Tags: vectors, covariance

Could someone explain in an intuitive and if possible as simple as possible manner (ideally with at least 1 example) the relationship between  covariance/contra-variance and row/col vectors ? E.g. like one can multiply e.g. a row vector by a matrix (of compatible size of course) and obtain the same result (but transposed) as multiplying the same matrix  with the same vector but on the right,  with that vector as a column vector this time (juste the same vector but transposed). It this also related to the contra-variance/covariance  concept and if yes how?
In math notation:
$Ax = (x^TA^T)^T$

Also: is there a  relationship with the fact that we have to multiply (a vector in standard basis) by the inverse change-of-basis-matrix to get the coordinates in the new basis, since co/contra-variance seems related to change of basis?

If have read multiple articles (wiki etc) , and understood some aspects but still not found a simple and minimal yet including the ascpects I mentioned,  explanation.

Also if possible, I would like a more intuitive (in the sense 'what is the concrete purpose of?' ) covectors... I seems to be like a kind of scalar product but still I cannot understand the meaning, usage and purpose of it and all the "dual space" thing/framework.

(I am aware that there are semi-similar questions on this forum related to this subject but the answers provided to them are not satisfactory for me and I also added the relationship aspects towards inverse change-of-basis-matrix matrix.)

Comment: I know that contravariants are superscripts and covariants are subscripts, that row indexes are superscripts and column indexes are subscripts, but honestly, I have the same question, and was going to ask their relations.

Comment: Maybe super/subs are contra/co if $A(x)$ is a tensor field, whereas, if something like $g(x)$ then it's a matrix.  I'm pretty sure this is the answer from page 93-94 of "Introductory Differential Geometry for Physicists" by A. Visconti.

Comment: Also, the row/column terms I used in the first comment are from pg. 10 of "An Introductory Course on Differentiable Manifolds" by Siavash Shahshahani.